# check if user inputted values exist in database then redirect to page

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am very new to PHP and MySQL, so I don't know where to start and need some guidance.

I am looking to create a simple page where the viewer can enter their last name and a receipt number and if the value exists in a MySQL database, I want it to redirect to a specific page. If not, then it can show a normal error message.

How do I start coding something like this?

Comment: Google "if row exists mysql"

Comment: look into ajax (javascript) have it call php to check in the database, ajax gets output from php make it say like {"status":true}, in javascript if the status is true then perform the redirect

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: You all are right. I apologize for how general this question is. I am still in the process of learning PHP & MySQL, but need this page up ASAP. I will continue to do more research and learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be nice, this is very very basic and needs a lot of work but its a starting point.

```
<?php


    if(isset($_POST['lastName']) && isset($_POST['receiptNumber'])){
        try{
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            error_log('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        try{
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE last_name=? AND receipt_number=?");
            $stmt->execute(array($_POST['lastName'], $_POST['receiptNumber']));

            $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            error_log('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }

        if(count($rows)){
            header('Location: some_page.php');
            die();  
        } else {
            $error = 'No Results Found';    
        }

    }

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php if(isset($error)){ echo $error; } ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="reciptNumber" placeholder="Receipt Number" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```